# Aparapium OpenCL not working on Manjaro Arch with NVidia graphic card

Tags: java, linux, opencl, nvidia

I'm having trouble building Aparapium library with NVidia 960M graphic card. I have propriety drivers, installed cuda, installed OpenCL for nvidia and Im trying to build for NVidia but only thing I get running is my intel build-in graphic card for when I run sketch (I'm using Intellij with Processing) I get following:

```
    devices={Intel<GPU>|Java Alternative Algorithm|Java Thread Pool}: FP64 required but not supported
```

I'm using modified Aparapi build file with nvidia support in it, and build says it went successfully but my sketch is always running on only Intel graphic card. I only gave build.xml a path to nvidia libOpenCL.so a not intel opencl-sdk. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi, Aparapi lead developer here. Could I see the edited source that adds in nvidia support. I'd like to see if it is anything worth adding to the project, thanks.

It may also help me solve your problem if you are still having it.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple program to compile, it displays all openCL devices, you could check it (github: marchv/opencl-info, its C++ cant find similar in java) . If it show yours NVidia GPU, you need to "tell" library to use another card. If there is no Nvidia GPU(platform) its probably problem with configuration/installation. Your laptop has Optimus technology?